# dont show record data in crystal report with dataset

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, dataset, report

hi I create a report with crystal report by using dataset

http://upload7.ir/images/59709775438148913038.jpg

my code for load report :

*Imports System.Data.SqlClient*

Public Class varede_report

```
Private Sub CrystalReportViewer1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CrystalReportViewer1.Load
    Dim rpt As New CrystalReport1
    Dim myconnection As SqlConnection
    Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand
    Dim myda As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim myds As New rt_DataSet
    Try
        myconnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\khatam.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")
        mycommand.Connection = myconnection
        mycommand.CommandText = "select * from letter1"
        mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        myda.SelectCommand = mycommand
        myda.Fill(myds, "letter1")
        rpt.SetDataSource(myds)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MessageBox.Show(Excep.Message, "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub varede_report_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

End Class

but when i run this app don't show table record from dataset in report
please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% up to speed on VB, but your code doesn't show anywhere to actually load the report. In C# you'd have something like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument();
reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
reportdocument.SetDatabaseLogon("username","password","SureshDasari","MySampleDB");
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument;
}
```

where the line `reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));` specifies the report. I don't see that in your code. So put something like `rpt.Load("PUT CRYSTAL REPORT PATH HERE\CrystalReport1.rpt")` in your CrystalReportViewer1_Load and see if that works.

Comment: Dim rpt As New CrystalReport1

Comment: That declares the variable rpt as a Crystal Report, but it doesn't specify the location of the report or tells the program to load the report.